# How to add rendersetting component to my root entity in qt3d?

Tags: opengl, qt3d

I am working on some codes about qt3d. I create a Qt3DWindow(named view).

Try to add a root entity(named rootEntity) in it.

Put a cube entity like this:

```
m_cubeEntity = new Qt3DCore::QEntity;
...
Qt3DExtras::QCuboidMesh *cubeMesh = new Qt3DExtras::QCuboidMesh;
Qt3DRender::QMaterial *cubeMaterial = new Qt3DRender::QMaterial;
Qt3DCore::QTransform *cubeTransform = new Qt3DCore::QTransform;
Qt3DRender::QObjectPicker *objectPicker = new Qt3DRender::QObjectPicker;
...
m_cubeEntity.addComponent(cubeMesh);
m_cubeEntity.addComponent(cubeMaterial);
m_cubeEntity.addComponent(cubeTransform);
m_cubeEntity.adComponent(objectPicker);

m_cubeEntity.setParent(m_rootEntity);
```

Everything works fine.

And then I find using PickingSettings.BoundingVolumePicking to pick my cube entity is inaccuracy. I want the PickingSettings.TrianglePicking. 
====================================================================/

So then i do it like this:

```
    m_renderSettings = new Qt3DRender::QRenderSettings();
    m_renderSettings->pickingSettings()->setPickMethod(Qt3DRender::QPickingSettings::TrianglePicking);
    m_renderSettings->pickingSettings()->setPickResultMode(Qt3DRender::QPickingSettings::AllPicks);
    m_renderer = new Qt3DExtras::QForwardRenderer();
    m_renderer->setClearColor(Qt::lightGray);
    m_renderSettings->setActiveFrameGraph(m_renderer);
    m_rootEntity->addComponent(m_renderSettings);
```

But now nothing is rendered. If i remove "m_renderSettings" from rootEntity, everything returns correct.

How to set rendersetting correctly for the root entity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely you just set a bad framegraph. You can easily display the standard framegraph using `dumpObjectTree()`, which tends to be a very useful function in debugging the framegraph of Qt3D.

For your simple use case it suffices to just use the `renderSettings` already contained in the `activeFrameGraph()` of the `Qt3DWindow`.

Just try the following simple app, that contains your desired `QObjectPicker`.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <Qt3DCore/QTransform>
#include <Qt3DRender/QPickEvent>
#include <Qt3DRender/QCamera>
#include <Qt3DRender/QFrameGraphNode>
#include <Qt3DRender/QObjectPicker>
#include <Qt3DExtras/QDiffuseSpecularMaterial>
#include <Qt3DExtras/QCuboidMesh>
#include <Qt3DExtras/Qt3DWindow>
#include <Qt3DRender/QRenderSettings>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    auto view = new Qt3DExtras::Qt3DWindow();

    auto rootEntity = new Qt3DCore::QEntity();
    view->setRootEntity(rootEntity);

    // Shows your framegraph! Simple forward renderer! 
    view->activeFrameGraph()->dumpObjectTree(); 
    auto rendersettings=view->renderSettings();
    rendersettings->pickingSettings()->setPickMethod(Qt3DRender::QPickingSettings::TrianglePicking);
    rendersettings->pickingSettings()->setPickResultMode(Qt3DRender::QPickingSettings::AllPicks);

    auto cameraEntity = view->camera();
    cameraEntity->lens()->setPerspectiveProjection(45.0f, 1., 0.1f, 10000.0f);
    cameraEntity->setPosition(QVector3D(0, 2, 0));
    cameraEntity->setUpVector(QVector3D(0, 1, 0));
    cameraEntity->setViewCenter(QVector3D(0, 0, 0));

    auto cubeEntity = new Qt3DCore::QEntity(rootEntity);
    auto cubeMesh = new Qt3DExtras::QCuboidMesh;
    cubeMesh->setXExtent(1.);
    cubeMesh->setYExtent(1.);
    auto cubeMaterial = new Qt3DExtras::QDiffuseSpecularMaterial;
    auto objectPicker = new Qt3DRender::QObjectPicker;

    QObject::connect(objectPicker, &Qt3DRender::QObjectPicker::clicked, [](Qt3DRender::QPickEvent* pick) {
        qDebug() << pick;
    });
    cubeEntity->addComponent(cubeMesh);
    cubeEntity->addComponent(cubeMaterial);
    cubeEntity->addComponent(objectPicker);

    view->show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly! Also, I want to say we had problems in customizing the Picker settings, until I found your post: the trick is to set them by using the `rendersettings` returned by the `view`! Thanks a lot for sharing! +1!